# PHP preg_replace - text will not be recognized

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have problems with preg_replace. The $insert_marker text will not be recognized and is caused by "$". If I remove the 2 $ characters, it works. So what is the problem?

```
function insert_into_file($file_path, $insert_marker, $text, $after = true) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($file_path);
    $new_contents = preg_replace($insert_marker, ($after) ? '$0' . $text : $text . '$0', $contents);
    return file_put_contents($file_path, $new_contents);
}

$file_path = ".htaccess";
$insert_marker = "/##-- $Id: _.htaccess 10934 2017-08-31 12:11:28Z serpent_driver $/";
$text = "\n##added text";

$num_bytes = insert_into_file($file_path, $insert_marker, $text, true);

if ($num_bytes === false) {
    echo "Could not insert into file $file_path.";
} else {
    echo "Insert successful!";
}
```

Comment: I did not understand what is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` is a special character for regex (it means end of line), you have to escape it: `\$` and because you are using a variable that contains the regex and pass it as a parameter of the function, you have to triple escape:

```
$insert_marker = "/##-- \\\$Id: _.htaccess 10934 2017-08-31 12:11:28Z serpent_driver \\\$/";
```

Comment: @RobertBaumann: Sorry, you have to triple escape the `$` --> `\\\$`

Comment: triple escape works, but at both $
$insert_marker = "/##-- \\\$Id: _.htaccess 10934 2017-08-31 12:11:28Z serpent_driver \\\$/";

Thank you so much!

Comment: @RobertBaumann: Sure, I didn't think that the last `$` was really a dollar sign but I believed it was end of line. You have to tripple escape **all** the dollar sign except for end of line.

Comment: Where is the box I can put money in it for a cup of coffee? :)

Comment: @RobertBaumann: Just here ;) [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to understand your question, but I figured out that you mean the `$Id` part of `$insert_marker` is causing issues. You need to escape the $ with a backslash, like so: `$insert_marker = "/##-- \$Id: _.htaccess 10934 2017-08-31 12:11:28Z serpent_driver $/";`

Comment: Sorry for hard understanding my question, but I thought the problem is obviously. It doesn't work with escaping $ and already tried before posting.

Comment: It might be worth adding a regex tag to this question, so those guys can have a look too. This is more of a regex issue than php tbh.